# Jboss 7.0 to Jboss 7.3 migration Issue with xsl files

Tags: xml, xslt, jboss, redhat

I am working on migrating the Jboss server from EAP 7.0 to EAP 7.3
We face an issue with xsl file getting loaded.

SystemId Unknown; Line #16; Column #42; xsl:stylesheet is not allowed in this position in the stylesheet!
(Location of error unknown)org.xml.sax.SAXException: Did not find the stylesheet root!
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Did not find the stylesheet root!

When I compared the log with 7.0 version (which is working good), I see the below redirect is not happening in 7.3 version.

```
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory = __redirected.__DatatypeFactory
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory = __redirected.__DocumentBuilderFactory
javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory = __redirected.__SAXParserFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLEventFactory = __redirected.__XMLEventFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory = __redirected.__XMLInputFactory
javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory = __redirected.__XMLOutputFactory
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory = __redirected.__TransformerFactory
javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory:http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema = __redirected.__SchemaFactory
javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:http://java.sun.com/jaxp/xpath/dom = __redirected.__XPathFactory

org.xml.sax.driver = __redirected.__XMLReaderFactory
```

Anyone have idea about this issue or any resolution ??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijcB2.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7e5s.png)

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this issue was adding
-Dorg.xml.sax.driver=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser to the VM Arguments.

Another solution was to add the org.xml.sax.driver file in modules\system\layers\base\sun\jdk\main\service-loader-resources\META-INF\services